# JSP`S session start and application start event function

Tags: java, jsp

in *ASPX*, it has `global.asax`, where you can define global function, such as

```
session_start //happend when user first visit
application_start //happend when server start
```

Does *JSP* or *Enterprise JAVA* have similar thing like this?

Comment: There are many listeners within a java web application, yours included.

Comment: A small overview can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/wls100/webapp/app_events.html). Just don't forget to annotate them, or add relevant information to web.xml.

Answer (score 3):

Java webapps can declare a [ServletContextListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) to be notified when the application is started and destroyed.

They can also declare an [HttpSessionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html) to be notified when a session is started and destroyed.